# Additional parameters to IdentityServer4 authorize url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm migrating a project using **ASP.NET MVC 5 with ASP.NET Identity** to **ASP.NET Core MVC, ASP.NET Core Identity and IdentityServer 4**.

The old web application use the **Katana OAuth2** server configured with a custom **OAuthController**, its Authorize action accepts 3 additional parameters for signing in already register mobile devices without redirecting them to login page or assigning them to the user signing in from them.

How can I do the same thing with **IdentityServer4**?

**Additional question:**

Is it possible to keep the same url scheme or do I need to create a rewrite policy?